# Rails: If page is NOT equal to current_page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to set a header to show links if the current_page is not equal to `root_path`.

I currently have the opposite, `<% if current_page?(root_path) %>`
which works fine. What is the style for adding the NOT EQUAL TO operator?

I have tried using `!=` ... but to no avail.

Comment: Why not just use `unless` instead of  `if`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the style for adding the NOT EQUAL TO operator?

not equal in Ruby is `!=`.

If I get you right, you're looking for something like this:

```
<% unless current_page?(root_path) %>
  <%= # do_something %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @Ryan Asensio do you have `current_page` helper defined?

Comment: I replaced it with ` <% unless current_page?(root_path) %>`  and it seems to work fine now. Those definitions are built it, but i guess calling it that way didn't let it recognize it.  Thanks Andrey